# Why is "service" pronounced the way it is?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is *service* pronounced the way it is and not like *device* even though the last 4 letters of the words are identical?

I would think that if they end the same way, the same pronunciation rules should apply as well.

I also checked Wiktionary.org and it says both words evolved from Old French where 'service' originated from 'servis' and 'device' originated from 'devis'. Again identical end of the word spelling.

Comment: In English orthography there are no rules, only tendencies!

Comment: Why is "service" pronounced so much like "crevice" – is that what you're asking?

Comment: _"I would think that if they end the same way, the same pronunciation rules should apply as well."_ Just like *head* and *bead*?  Or *bough, cough, rough, though,* and *through*? It's hard to make that kind of assertion about a language that gives us the likes of *live* and *live*, *read* and *read*, and *wind* and *wind*.

Comment: @J.R. Do you mean that English pronunciation is kind of [chaotic](http://www.madore.org/~david/misc/english-pronunciation.html)? Let's [see...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0hjhu1rUKM)

Comment: "the same pronunciation rules" I don't think we generally have pronunciation rules in English. Spellings were normally made to represent pronunciations, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is due to the [Great Vowel Shift](http://www.courses.fas.harvard.edu/~chaucer/vowels.html).

In Middle English the "i" in *device* used to be prounounced as in *service* but later shifted to a /ai/ diphtong because it was bearing the stress.

Comment: I can't speak to the history, and I'm not an OF scholar, so I can't say what stress, if any, the words had before they migrated across the Channel. But certainly anyone who used the words would be aware that the orthographic identity of the endings is accidental:  *service* is *serv-* with a suffix, *device* is *vis-* with a prefix. That sets the stress, after which the GVS takes over.

Comment: This has less to do with GVS, more to do with stress, as John Lawler described.

Comment: Well I think it has to do with both, the sounds used to be the same (length excepted) and diverged during the GVS because one was stressed and the other was not.

Answer (score 12):

It's entirely a matter of syllable stress. English is a [stress-timed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrony#Stress_timing). Only a stressed syllable can have a full vowel in English; unstressed syllables are centralized and reduced as much as possible, especially in rapid speech.

*SERvice* is stressed on the first syllable, so the vowel in the first syllable gets fully pronounced ['sɝ], while the second unstressed syllable is reduced to shwa [vəs].

On the hand, *deVICE* is stressed on the **second** syllable, so the vowel in **that** syllable gets fully pronounced ['vəys], while the first unstressed syllable is reduced to shwa [də].

Spelling has very little to do with pronunciation in English; its spelling was invented for a different language and doesn't work at all well for modern English. This fact explains a lot of other things, including why you shouldn't be worried if it's not logical. In fact, you're right. -- it's **not** logical.

Comment: How do [unstressed full vowels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_vowels_in_English#Unstressed_full_vowels) work?

Comment: I suspect they're less common in American than in British speech. I rarely come across them.

Comment: Are you sure?  You reduce *chromosome, ambition, humanity, tofu, Pleistocene, pharoah, kryptonite, plaintain*?  I don’t believe I’ve heard such an accent.  I bet you don’t reduce those.

Comment: ['kroməˌsom, ˌæm'bɪʃn, ˌyʊ'mænəɾi, 'toˌfu, 'playstəˌsin, ... ] Apparently secondary stress is against someone's religion; but not mine.

Comment: You seem to be defining “secondary stress” as “not stressed but having unreduced vowels”, and defining “unstressed” as “not stressed and having reduced vowels”.  Is that correct?

Comment: No. Secondary stress is a lower peak in amplitude than primary stress, but still a peak. Especially in compound words, there are usually several potential stress points, as laid out by the morphology -- _reCIProcate, reciPROcity, reciproCAtion_ -- and any of them may bear secondary stress in a given utterance, depending on what the speaker intends to imply and to whom, how fast they're talking, how seriously they expect to be taken, and a few dozen other criteria.

Comment: The most interesting part of what you said is the bit about how seriously they expect to be taken.  I don’t know that I’ve ever realized that was a factor.

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation of *device* might actually be considered less predictable than the pronunciation of *service* (if we compare them to words like *novice* and *crevice*). But then again, in the word *advice* we have the same pronunciation as in *device*. The stress pattern of *device* and *advice* may be related to their morphology: in both words, the first syllable was originally a prefix. It may also be related to the existence of the verbs *devise* and *advise*; if so, another similar example may be [*abuse* n. and *abuse* v](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105435/why-dont-use-verb-noun-pairs-obey-initial-stress-derivation).

I'm going to ignore the presence of the letter "v", since I don't think it adds much information. So, here are some overall tendencies I see for the pronunciation of [words that end with *-ice*](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/ice/).

Monosyllabic words ending in *-ice* all have /aɪs/ (unless the *i* is part of a vowel digraph, as in *voice, juice, sluice*). Some examples: *ice, price, spice, slice.*

Polysyllabic words derived from these also have /aɪs/, such as *de-ice, re-price, overspice.*

Most other polysyllabic words ending in *-ice* have fully unstressed /ɪs/ or /əs/.
Of the words pronounced like this, most are nouns. There are some verbs, such as *notice* and *apprentice*, but they all have corresponding nouns spelled and pronounced the same way. In U.S. English, the verb *practice* also falls in this category. In British English the verb is spelled *practise*, although standardly pronounced the same as the noun. The OED has an interesting note about *practise*:

> The word was originally stressed on the second syllable [...] and this is still the
>   case in some regional varieties, especially in Scots (hence such
>   spellings as *practize, practeeze, practeese*). The stress was
>   subsequently shifted to the first syllable, with devoicing of the
>   final consonant, probably by association with *practice* n.

Some examples, with the stressed vowel in **bold**: ***crev***ice, **just**ice, **latt**ice, **not**ice, **nov**ice, **art**ifice, **av**arice, **ed**ifice, **or**ifice, ac**comp**lice, ap**prent**ice, in**ter**stice.

A small number of polysyllabic words have /aɪs/; as mentioned in other answers, these words always have primary or tertiary stress on the last syllable (and none of them have primary stress on the second-to-last syllable). This category has a greater proportion of verbs. (The reason why I've discussed part of speech is that in English verbs are generally more likely than nouns to have some degree of stress on the final syllable; we can see this in contrasts like *associate* n. versus *associate* v., or the noun ending *-ity* versus the verb ending *-ify*.) As StoneyB mentions in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78509/why-is-service-pronounced-the-way-it-is#comment154308_78512), the stress may also be affected when the first syllable of a word comes from a Latin prefix. Here is a list of all the words like this I found, with the primary-stressed syllable in **bold**:

- *ad**vice*** n. (pairs with *advise* v.; from Latin past participle *vīsum* with the preposition/prefix *a(d-)* )
- *de**vice*** n. (pairs with *devise* v.; apparently ultimately from Latin *dīvīs-/dīvidere*, from *videre* with the prefix *dis-*)
- *en**tice*** v. (from Vulgar Latin *intitiāre*, with the prefix *in-*)
- *suf**fice*** v. (from Latin  *sufficere*, with the prefix *sub-*)
- ***sac***rifice n., v. (from French, ultimately from Latin *sacrificium.* The OED says the verb was derived from the noun)
- ***sat***isfice v. (note: this word was coined by combining *satisfy* and *suffice*)
- ***cock***atrice n. (however, this word is also pronounced with /ɪs/)

There are also a couple of words spelled with *-ice* that are usually pronounced with stressed /iːs/: *po**lice**, ca**price**.* They were borrowed relatively recently from French, and don't show the signs of the Great Vowel shift.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb a little but, I'm fairly sure that words that have two consonants followed by "ice" are pronounced like service. Words where "ice" is preceded by a vowel and consonant are pronounced like device.

Comment: I believe just one example will **suffice** to disprove that theory :-)

Comment: That's cheating ;) it's really one letter. One sounded letter anyway. I need to go and hide my shame in a crevice.

Comment: Please play nice.

Comment: While your theory is enticing, I can't help noticing counterexamples.

Comment: I was playfully admitting defeat. I'll do a pattern match today for words ending in ice. I can only think of very few.

Comment: Had a look. There's only about a dozen or so of words where the letter pattern is vowel, consonant and followed by "ice." The only exception for pronunciation in this group is "sacrifice." The sixy or so words that aren't in the above group don't follow much pattern in pronunciation. I think i've proven my answer thoroughly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Great vowel shift split them,people used to say them the same then they took different roads

Service sɛrviːs > sɜɹvɪis > sɚvəs/sɜves(sairvees > sairvihys > servihs > srrvuhs/suhvuss)

Device  dɛviːs > devɪis > dɪvəɪs>dəvæɪs(dehvees > dehvihys > duhvuhys > duhvaahys)

I am not exactly sure how and at what combination did the vowels change but the above is pretty much what happened)