# Is "take a bath" or "bathe" used to mean "take a shower" in some English dialects?

Tags: american-english, british-english, dialects, non-standard

By analogy with Portuguese [***tomar banho***](http://dictionary.reverso.net/portuguese-english/banho) [[de chuveiro/ducha](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/portuguese-english/tomar-banho)], which along with ***tomar uma ducha/chuveirada*** (*Br.*)/***duche*** (*Port.*) means, ***take a shower***,

are there any parts of the English speaking world in which one can hear phrases like

> ***take a bath***
>
> and/or ***bathe***,

be commonly (not to say *idiomatically*) used to mean, ***take a shower***, in such a way that the word ***shower*** in such regions is exclusively used to call the shower apparatus?

> bathe
>
> : to bathe oneself; take a bath **or shower** (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/bathe)
>
> bath
>
> **a washing or immersion of something**, especially the body, in water, steam, etc., as for cleansing or medical treatment:
>   *I take a bath every day*.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bath)

For example,

> *I was in the shower **bathing**/**taking a bath** when the telephone rang.*
>
> *I **bathe** [=take a shower] every day, but I can't seem to remember the last time I **took a bath**.*

Comment: I've never heard *anyone* (not even American) say anything like *Would you like to **bathe** before dinner?* - it's *take a bath* or *take a shower* (or maybe *wash [up]*, but I generally understand that to mean hands and at most face, not whole-body ablution). *Chez moi* people routinely say they're going to have a bath or go to the bathroom when they're actually talking about the *shower [room]* (even though they know there's also a bath in a bathroom elsewhere in the house).

Comment: Unless you were going swimming before eating...

Comment: I've heard people (mainly Americans) talk about going to the bathroom even when it's just a urinal (perhaps without even a *washbasin*, let alone a bath). It's probably a false memory, but I even seem to recall an American student decades ago saying he was going to the bathroom when it was a [pissoir](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Pissoir_2.JPG)

Comment: Almost a duplicate of: [“to bath” vs “to bathe”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206047/to-bath-vs-to-bathe)

Comment: Are you saying that some native speakers say "*take a bath*", "*bathe*" or "*bath*" in place of "taking/having a shower"?

Comment: @Elian You have massively confused the question with your AmE/BrE interpolations. But the biggest confusion is the "[bath of]" in the last sentence, which introduces an ungrammaticality. Just ask the question already!

Comment: What @AndrewLeach said: Please rephrase the question. It can no doubt be made simpler and clearer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You are correct, and your memory wrt "pissoir" is probably correct as well. *Go to the bathroom* is a common AmE euphemism for using the toilet. *Bathroom* is the most common name for a room, in a house, that has any combination of sink, toilet, bathtub, and shower. *Restroom* is a common name for a public room that has toilets and possibly urinals.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I feel sure some Americans talk about *going to the bathroom* before nipping behind a tree when out for a walk in the country.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes. My wife, who is Malaysian (English and Chinese native speaker) talks about *taking a bath* when she means a shower. That's even after living in Britain most of her adult life. Fumble Fingers suggests people *chez soi* (presumably in Britain) say that. But it doesn't really accord with my own experience.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I remember that some years ago I said to an American that, to us Brits, a *bathroom* is a room with a bath.  The response was that she had never thought of it like that!  Having said that, we have a room containing a toilet & shower, which we tend to call a *bathroom* rather than a *shower room* - but we also call the room with a toilet & a bath, a *bathroom*!

Comment: "to bathe oneself; take a bath or shower" ... Yes.

Comment: @Mazura Do you mean that you already heard some native speaker(s) say "take a bath" or "bathe" to mean "shower/take a shower"?

Comment: A personally attested, *yes*. I bathe everyday but I can't remember the last time I took a bath. Colloquially, both are either, but much less so with "take a bath".

Comment: @Mazura You might consider to post this as an answer. :-)

Comment: How could anyone prove that a speaker who says: *I take a bath every day* OR *I have a bath everyday* OR *I bathe everyday* is referring to "taking/having a shower"?  The term *shower* is hardly obscure or unusual, is it? Yes, maybe they just mean washing their bodies, in which case a washcloth and a basin could do just as well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Apparently, some native speakers do use "bathe" and "shower" interchangeably. "By the way, in my area, most people use "shower" and "bathe" interchangeably. I say "I bathe every day", but I mean that I take showers. I don't take baths.)" https://www.tellwut.com/surveys/lifestyle/living/81564-do-you-take-a-bath-everyday-.html

Comment: @Mazura You've confirmed that "native speakers" including yourself use *bathe* to mean *take a bath* or *take a shower*, but you don't say native where and your profile doesn't indicate where you are from.  Please clarify: English speakers from where - England, USA, India, Australia, ...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking users to read people's minds. It's impossible to know for certain if people mean "shower" when they say "bath".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, in the US a *bathroom* is a place with a toilet and sink.  The actual tub/shower is optional.  (When selling homes the toilet-only room is called a "half bath" while the one with tub is a "full bath", and it's a "three-quarters bath" if it's got toilet and shower but no tub.)  However, in businesses and other public buildings the toilet room is more commonly referred to as a *restroom*.

And even when the "facilities" are no more elaborate than a shed with pit underneath it, the typical American English speaker may very well refer to it as "the bathroom" out of habit, though in this case the term "toilet" is more apt to be used.

When describing his intent to bathe his entire body, the typical American English speaker would say he was going to "take a bath".  If he intended to shower only, he might instead express that qualification by saying he was going to "take a shower".  It's vaguely possible he might express an intent to "bathe", but that's a rather quaint way to say it.

If the typical American English speaker needed to perform an excretory function he would say he needed to "go to the bathroom" (possibly substituting some euphemism for "bathroom"), or, particularly before/after a meal, he might say he needed to "wash up".  And it would not be unusual for a host to courteously ask if a guest would like to "wash up" before a meal (or perhaps simply after arriving in the house following a lengthy journey).  *On re-reading this it occurs to me that "use the bathroom" would be more idiomatic (and slightly more polite) than "go to the bathroom", since "go" implies excretion while "use" is more ambiguous.*

(But note that these are "typical American English" terms, and it's entirely possible that different terms are used in West Boston or some such, as is common with domestic terms.)

Comment: In England, if a host invited you to "wash up" it would seem as if they were asking you to wash the dishes before the meal!  "Wash up" or "Do the washing up" is the normal expression for washing the dishes over here.